# Why TensorFlow with multiple GPUs give me this error?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[20000,20,20,20,16]   [[Node: Conv3D = Conv3D[T=DT_FLOAT, padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Reshape, Variable/read)]]   [[Node: Mean_2/_23 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_42_Mean_2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Please learn to provide a [MCVE]. A simple dump of an error message may not be enough to understand what's wrong or which part of the message you did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

> OOM when allocating tensor with shape[20000,20,20,20,16]

**Wild guess**: your batch size set to `20000` doesn't fit in the memory of your device (OOM = Out Of Memory). (FYI, that float tensor requires 20000*20*20*20*16*4 = 9.54 GBytes of memory)
Without code, though, that's about all I can say.

My second wild guess is that you attempted to define a big batch and have it automatically split among devices, but that's not how Tensorflow's data parallelism work with multiple devices. Have a look at the [Distributed Tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) for examples on how to do that.

*Please rewrite your question so that it contains a runnable example to reproduce your problem*.

Comment: Requests to improve a question should be made as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: And a comment about it was already present. My answer is what it is: a suggestion to solve his problem, with attached a request for more details to improve my answer further.